# How can I remove empty xmlns attribute from node created by XElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

This is my code:

```
XElement itemsElement = new XElement("Items", string.Empty);
//some code
parentElement.Add(itemsElement);
```

After that I got this:

```
<Items xmlns=""></Items>
```

Parent element hasn't any namespace. What can I do, to get an `Items` element without the empty namespace attribute?

Comment: The parent not having an explicit namespace can mean it inherits it from an ancestor. Does any element in the ancestor chain expose a namespace?

Comment: Yes. Some parents have namespace. But direct parent of Items hasn't. What's more. Each element of Items hasn't namespace.

Comment: If you're looking for <Items></Items>, than you could try remove string.Empty in XElement constructor.

Comment: I tried it too. But it doesn't working.

Comment: @ogrod, then you should set the same namespace as the one defined in the closest ancestor element, i.e. if you have `<ancestor xmlns="urn:foo"><!-- other elements... --><item></item><!-- other elements... --></ancestor>`, then you should apply `xmlns="urn:foo"` to the `<item>` element as well.

Comment: @Frederic: I did that, and I got Item with the same namespace as parent node. I want to get Item without any namepsace.

Comment: If the element has the same default namespace as the parent, then it should not have an `xmlns` attribute. Are you trying to set that attribute by hand instead of using an `XNamespace`? Can you post the markup of the ancestor element that has a namespace defined?

Comment: All right, now it's working :) I copied namespace with attribute from parent element. Now, I add only namespace, without attribute, and it's working. Thank you ;)

Comment: you should change your question because the solution is not the answer to what you asked.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It's all about how you handle your namespaces. The code below creates child items with different namespaces:

```
XNamespace defaultNs = "http://www.tempuri.org/default";
XNamespace otherNs = "http://www.tempuri.org/other";

var root = new XElement(defaultNs + "root");
root.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "otherNs", otherNs));

var parent = new XElement(otherNs + "parent");
root.Add(parent);

var child1 = new XElement(otherNs + "child1");
parent.Add(child1);

var child2 = new XElement(defaultNs + "child2");
parent.Add(child2);

var child3 = new XElement("child3");
parent.Add(child3);
```

It will produce XML that looks like this:

```
<root xmlns:otherNs="http://www.tempuri.org/other" xmlns="http://www.tempuri.org/default">
    <otherNs:parent>
        <otherNs:child1 />
        <child2 />
        <child3 xmlns="" />
    </otherNs:parent>
</root>
```

Look at the difference between `child1`, `child2` and `child3`. `child2` is created using the default namespace, which is probably what you want, while `child3` is what you have now.

Comment: I think the code in this answer will result in `"System.Xml.XmlException: 'The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.'"`. To avoid this use `new XElement(XName.Get("child1", otherNs));` in place of `new XElement(otherNs + "child1");`

Comment: @cedd Did you try it? It works on my machine. In fact, `Console.Out.WriteLine(root.ToString());` produces exactly what I show in the answer above. I'm running this in a Console app on .Net Framework 4.6.2. What did you do to get this error?

Comment: @cedd Ok, I can force that exact error if I use `var` when declaring the namespaces. They will then become `string`s, which will not work. They must be explicitly typed as `XNamespace`.