# Empty xmlns is created

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xelement

I add an `Xelement` to a parent `Xelement`:

```
rootElement.Add(schemaRootTag);
```

The new XML element has an empty `xmlns` attribute like: `xmlns=""`.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you saving the XML?

Comment: @AndreiV, Likt this: `xdoc.Save(path +".xml");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been asked here before.  It's all to do with how you create the XElement:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12039383/616304